# Flutter app crashes on firebase phone number authentication in Android platform

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have implemented Firebase Phone authentication in my Flutter project. The process crashes after I clicked "login", the app crashes and lost connection.

Below are the codes (get from the internet):

**main.dart**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginpage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**loginpage.dart**

```
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  String phoneNo, smssent, verificationId;

  Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verID) {
      this.verificationId = verID;
    };
    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int forceCodeResent]) {
      this.verificationId = verId;
      smsCodeDialogue(context).then((value) {
        print("Code Sent");
      });
    };
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential auth) {};
    final PhoneVerificationFailed verifyFailed = (AuthException e) {
      print('${e.message}');
    };
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNo,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
      verificationFailed: verifyFailed,
      codeSent: smsCodeSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
    );
  }

  Future<bool> smsCodeDialogue(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return new AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Enter OTP'),
            content: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                this.smssent = value;
              },
            ),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                      );
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      signIn(smssent);
                    }
                  });
                },
                child: Text(
                  "done",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  Future<bool> signIn(String smsCode) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
        ),
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text('PhoneNumber Login'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter your phone number",
                ),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  this.phoneNo = value;
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10.0,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: verifyPhone,
            child: Text(
              "verify",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            elevation: 7.0,
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**this is the error**

```
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

May I know what is the problem? Anyone would like to help me to solve this...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897637/flutter-firebase-phone-authentication-problem-app-closes-abruptly/65897742#65897742 please refer tthis question. because of similar question I am closing this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter firebase phone authentication problem. App closes abruptly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897637/flutter-firebase-phone-authentication-problem-app-closes-abruptly)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by simply adding below line into app/build.gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"
```

}

Comment: This will not solve the issue the question is having.

Answer (score 0):

I had also face the problem of app crashing when OTP is received and immediately app crashes, for that I added below dependency to android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"   // this is important
}
```